# С какой технологии быстрее стартануть в IT ?

Tags: работа

Доброго вам всего форумчане ! Я работаю один год на предприятии где программирую контроллеры для станков и прошивки для различного очень большого оборудования, из знаний это чистый Си и Ассемблер а также SQL, очень слабо знаком с ООП на примере С++. Моя зарплата 250 баксов и НИКАКОЙ перспективы !!! Я хочу очень быстро куда ни-буть свалить, но не хочу убить ещё год или два на изучение например С++ где перспективы так же туманны. Смотрел в сторону JavaEE, а там такой зоопарк надо знать : Spring, Hibernate, XML, XSL, XSLT, xsd, Design Patterns, Unix/Linux, SVN,Tomcat, JBOSS application servers, JIRA, IDE (Eclipse, IntelliJ), SaaS, Web Services, SOAP, REST, WSDL
что года два всё это точно учить надо. Для себя выбрал уйти в MobileDev будь то Android или iOS или взяться за C# так как на первый взгляд вроде это проще выучить и быстрее (наверно месяцев 6) и легче, а также платят 500 баксов джуну. Может я ошибаюсь, но так подскажите коллеги как быстрее стартануть я же загнусь скоро.
PS: английский учу по выходным и понимаю что он нужен.

Comment: @MAX_IM, либо переезжайте и работайте на нормальную зп, либо ищите удаленку(опять таки зп будет намного лучше), я тоже живу в небольшом городке, но это не повод работать за еду, хотя я не уверен что и на еду вам хватает, о жилье я молчу.

Ну и по поводу скорости старта - ИМХО, в вашем ужастном случае, из всего вами перечисленного, всему можно научится, на уровне джуна, куда быстрее чем за полгода, но я понимаю почему у вас такая планка, крайне рекомендую изучить рынок труда и посмотреть уровни з/п и требования (только везде, а не только там, где вы живете ибо у вас там п....).

Удачи

Comment: Даааа, у нас тут в Москве и 3000$ мало, а тут - 250...

Comment: >Даааа, у нас тут в Москве и 3000$ мало, а тут - 250...

@danpetruk не преувеличивайте. 3000 - это вполне неплохая оплата работы программиста, а для человека, у которого  опыт работы - один год - это отличная зарплата. Если это действительно программист, а не ведущий разработчик. Конечно, всегда можно найти примеры типа "А мой знакомый Васька Пупкин ничего не умеет, но получает 5000$", но это общей картины не составляет.

Comment: @DreamChild ну ещё от направления зависит. Знаю, что андродевелоперы получают 4000$, а JEEшники вообще 6000-7000$

Comment: @danpetruk пруф в студию, где человек с опытом в один год получает по 7000 американских денег

Comment: $7000 будет получать не меньше чем тим лид, девелопер умрет но такие бабки не получит никогда.

Comment: @Barmaley похоже, тут имеет место быть идеализация Java. Будь все так сказочно, все бы ринулись учить именно ее

Comment: @DreamChild во времена dot com пузыря так и было - помню домохозяйки и студенты все ринулись изучать Java

Answer (score 15):

Удивительно, где вы смогли найти работу за 250 долларов, зная асм и Си. Я согласен с [[@alex91](/users/10388/alex91)](/users/10388/alex91) - это стоит гораздо дороже. Судя по всему, вас либо очень круто обманывают, либо работаете вы в каком-то бесперспективном болоте. Так или иначе, вам явно стоит  всерьез задуматься о смене работы. 
Теперь по порядку.

1. Зная Java вы точно не пропадете - как-никак один из самых востребованных языков.Учить, конечно, придется немало, после ассемблера и Си многое покажется необычным (но скорее всего более удобным), но все же для того, чтобы получить работу хотя бы за 1000 долларов - явно не два года, а несколько меньше (учитывая, что вы уже год программируете, обучение будет не с нуля)
2. C# - многом ситуация похожа на Java - платят примерно одинаково, сложность тоже сопоставима, число  ваканский, если не ошибаюсь, примерно такое же (да, C# не проще Java, и зоопарк технологий там тоже сопоставим)
3. PHP - работы навалом, в том числе и за значительно большие, чем у вас сейчас деньги...Но Переходить с ассемблера и Си на PHP...хм...дело исключительно ваше, но по мне - это как с истребителя пересесть на кукурузник (но это имхо)
4. Можно остаться на Си (как вариант - перейти на плюсы) Вакансий на них значительно меньше, чем для вышеуказанных языков, но платят там опять же хорошие деньги, и переучиваться во многом будет не нужно
5. Можно еще вспомнить про Delphi (но с ним все не очень радужно), JavaScript (но чистый JS без чего-либо еще нужен не особо часто), Python, Ryby (по ним я вам сказать ничего не смогу - не знаком)

Да, и еще, маленькое, но довольно ваожное замечание - если захотите связать дальнейшую деятельность с web, то стоит помнить, что поначалу многое может даваться тяжело. Не то что бы web-прогаммирование сложнее, но у него явно мало общего с программированием станков

И вот еще что: не знаю, как насчет провинции (и того, где вы живете), но в Москве даже в самой нищебродской конторе junior-разработчику на C# платят около 1000 долларов, а не 500, как вы указали в вопросе.

Ну и постскриптум.
Что касается зоопарка:

> а там такой зоопарк надо знать : Spring, Hibernate, XML, XSL, XSLT, xsd, Design Patterns, Unix/Linux, SVN,Tomcat, JBOSS application servers, JIRA, IDE (Eclipse, IntelliJ), SaaS, Web Services, SOAP, REST, WSDL

не преувеличивайте масштаб трагедии - половина указанного не имеет прямого отношения к Java (а кое-что и непрямого не имеет). Также у вас тут многое смешано из разных областей деятельности, и все вместе вряд ли где-то понадобится. Кроме того, джуниору всё это знать не очень обязательно. Всему свое время.

Comment: Большое спасибо что так подробно ответили, да конечно наша контора в провинции, многие ушли давно остался я один и при этом меня ещё гнобят что я не успеваю всё сделать за рабочую смену. Хочу просто уйти куда-нибуть ...

Comment: ну так и идите. Если все действительно так, как описываете, то через год-другой ваша контора останется у разбитого корыта - программисты - это не те люди сейчас, с кем можно настолько по-скотски обращаться, потому что нормальный программист сможет запросто найти хорошую работу. Это, скажем, рабочему с завода идти некуда - на другом заводе платят так же, а у программиста масса вариантов

Comment: @MAX_IM: подумайте, возможно ли обеспечивать семью и детей на 250 долларов в месяц. Если ответ отрицательный, бегите оттуда немедленно. И да, программистам столько не платят, ищите работу за нормальные деньги и переезжайте в другой город.

Comment: @Vlad на эти деньги сейчас разве что кота можно обеспечивать. Но все же, выбирая между котом и семьей я сделаю выбор в польщу последней, как бы я ни любил котов.

Comment: Да причем тут семья и дети? Потратить так много сил и времени на изучение программирования что-бы работать за такие копейки это сильно не уважать себя, как известно, об людей, которые себя не уважают, обычно, вытирают ноги все, кому не лень.

Ладно еще если такой человек просто отвратительный специалист, тогда хоть ясно с чем этим связано.

не могу не прокоментировать высказывание

> у программиста масса вариантов

Да, это так, но действительно стоящих и/или интересных, все равно, всегда очень мало

Comment: >Да, это так, но действительно стоящих и/или интересных, все равно, всегда очень мало

@AlexWindHope обратите внимание на то, что речь тут не об интересе, а об элементарном несоответствии зарплаты прожиточному минимуму. Тут уж не до интересностей, знаете ли

Comment: @DreamChild, я комментировал ваше высказывание вне контекста текущего вопроса.

Comment: > Можно еще вспомнить про Delphi (но с ним все не очень радужно)

частенько мелькают вакансии в москве, з/п от 100к рублей.

Comment: речь о том, что звездный час Delphi уже давно прошел. Embarcadero что-то  там старается (и вроде бы даже ее старания вполне достойно выглядят) но вакансий все меньше, да и сводятся они в основном к допиливанию древнего кода на Delphi 7.

Для сравнения зашел на hh, посмотрел выдачи  по запросам "программист С#" и "программист Delphi" без выставления каких-либо еще условий. В результате по первому запросу 1783 вакансии, по второму - 457. Если взглянуть на еще более популярные PHP/JS и Java, то соотношение для Delphi еще хуже. Делайте выводы.

Answer (score 5):

Добавлю свои 5 копеек, касательно зоопарков для Java.

Это на первый взгляд зоопарк технологий, но на самом то деле все достаточно жестко структурировано. Наиболее востребованы web технологии для Java. А там 1 царь и король - Servlet/JSP - это краеугольный камень на котором весь этот зоопарк построен. Надо хорошо знать именно Servlet/JSP, а все остальное к нему легко подтягивается. 2-й краеугольный камень это владение способов работы с БД/SQL - JDBC/Hibernate. Вплотную примыкает к этому XML. XSLT - не советую терять времени, это так сказать только для разнообразия.

И еще не теряйте времени на изучение EJB/JMS/Applet и проч. полумертвых технологий. Они конечно используются, но в реальной практике предложений по ним будет совсем мизер.

Относительно мало предложений по Swing и WSDL (особенно Swing). Их знать конечно надо, но это можно освоить потом.

По серверам: достаточно знать Tomcat, а все остальное JBOSS/WebLogic/WebSphere - никто не будет вас к этому обязывать. Если нормально владеть конфигурированием Tomcat, то справиться с остальными дело техники. Тем более что принципы все равно одни и те же.

По среде разработки: да их огромное количество. Но я еще не встречал случая, чтобы человека из-за незнания (читай отсутсвия опыта) скажем Eclipse (при знании Intellij) не взяли бы на работу. Так что выберите себе 1 среду разработки из 3-х основных китов: Intellij, Eclipse и Netbeans и работайте с ним.

В общем подводя резюме, схема быстрого Java старта такая:

1. Определяемся со средой разработки (Intellij, Eclipse, Netbeans)
2. Учим Servlet/JSP в качестве сервера берем Tomcat
3. Учим JDBC/Hibernate с SQL сервером Derby/SQLite/Hypersonic SQL
4. Накидываем сверху пару фреймворков: начинаем со Struts, заканчиваем Spring - на этом же этапе придет понимание паттернов/BluePrints

Answer (score 3):

Чистый Си и ассемблер - 250 долларов даже для провинции - очень странно. Это стоит дороже.

Answer (score 2):

Думаю неважно какую область вы выберите, просто надо быть монстром в той области который вы находитесь. Не надо гнаться за деньгами надо гнаться за знаниями, и тогда деньги за вами будут гнаться:)

Answer (score 0):

Если знаете Си, то будет легко стартануть на PHP + есть знание MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

По своему опыту, для джунор-девелопера нужны в первую очередь не знания синтаксиса языков, а понимание задач. То есть на собеседовании Вас скорее всего спросят не "как написать лямбда-выражение", а "Вам делегировали задачу: сделать что-то. С чего Вы начнете?" А как использовать конкретные технологии Вас научат или, как минимум, дадут возможность научиться, уже по ходу работы. Именно для этого и существует позиция джуниор-девелопера.